# How to find the iteration in which the continue-sattement takes place in python

Tags: python, for-loop, continue

I have a `for` loop and a `continue` statement in it in python. I want to know the number of iteration in which the `continue` statement took place. I mean:

```
count=0
for i in range (5):
    if i == 3:
        count+=1
        continue
    print (i)
```

The `count` value tells me that `1` time I have faced the `continue` in my `for` loop. But I want to know in which iteration was it, which obviously is the fourth iteration (after printing 0, 1 and 2). In reality I may get into `continue` several time and this is only a simple example to clarify my proble. I do appreciate if anyone let me know how to find it out. In advance, thanks for any help.

Comment: if you want to store the values. I will suggest you to use class so that you can use the value anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time `continue`  is run, add the current index to count. At the end the count list will contain all the indexes in which `continue` has been executed. The length of count will tell you how many times `continue` has been run.

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
        count = []
        for i in range(5):
            if i == 3:
                count.append(i+1) #because iter starts with 0
                continue
            print(i)
    print(count)
    print(len(count))
```

**Clarification**

You can change `i+1` with `i`, it depends on how you want to interpret it. In general it depends on whether you want to take into account that the iteration started from 0 or not.

Comment: Dear @Wippo, Thanks for your help. Your solution is telling me in which value my continue has ben run. If you select a range like `range (5,10)` and select `i==7`, Then it will again gives you `7` as the count. While it should be `3`.

Comment: in that case do (i+1)-start, where start = 5

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to go about this.

1. Modifying your code slightly:

```
>>> count = 0
>>> for i in range(5):
...     count += 1
...     if i == 3:
...             print(f"Loop continued at iteration {count}")
...             continue
...     print(i)
...
0
1
2
Loop continued at iteration 4
4
```

2. Using `enumerate`, for a more 'pythonic' solution:

```
>>> for iter, i in enumerate(range(5), start=1):
...     if i == 3:
...             print(f"Loop continued at iteration {iter}")
...             continue
...     print(i)
...
0
1
2
Loop continued at iteration 4
4
```

Comment: Dear @navneethc, Thanks for your help. I do appreciate it. Can I just simple have the number of iteration in which continue happened? I want to use this number in a function. I mean I cannot check it and then use it. Can I store it as a variable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- how's my answer different from what you want? Your original post said that you wanted to know "in which iteration"  a continuation occurred.

Comment: Your answer is completely correct. I just want to save the number as a varable and not in the for loop.

Comment: If you expect to have only 1 such position, you can assign it to a variable within the loop. That variable will be available outside the loop as well. If you expect more, then you can create an empty list outside the loop and append each position to it as you encounter it.

Answer (score 1):

```
count=0
for i in range (5):
    if i/3 == 0:
        count+=1
        continue
    print (i)
```

Your code should like this but in this code for-loop continues forever
if you want write i to screen each times use the code below

```
count=0
for i in range (5):
    if i/3 == 0:
        count+=1
        print (i)
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class to store the values.

```
class info():
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.iter = []

    def increment(self):
        self.counter += 1


a = info()
for i in range(5):
    a.increment()
    if i%2: 
        if i!=5:
            a.iter.append(i+1)
        continue
print(a.counter, a.iter)
```

---

```
5 [2, 4]
```

see: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/3WrtCiH2PD